# Swift - Do something in tableview after data is loaded

Tags: swift, uitableview, reloaddata

In my UItableview i have a custom-cell. Are there any way to check when the cellForRow have launched and all tableview cells has loaded the content?

Comment: Unless all of your cells fit on the screen without scrolling, they're never all done, because every scroll action can cause cells to be reloaded.

Comment: Well for a start what if you have 1000 cells?  They will never all load at once.  If you mean all 'visible' cells you can't even really do that.  Why do you want to do this in the first place?